# Login with google using google plus api on website for UserInfo and contacts using contact api

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-oauth

I have implemented login with google using google plus api. I have achieved the basic steps but still have some doubts which can be errors for my project in coming future or currently also.

What I have accomplished :

1. got google user profile info.
2. got email id
3. got the contacts of the google logged in account.

Problems and doubts I am facing are:

1. Once I logged in using google account on clicking a button in my website and  just logout from my website,then I am unable to again login in my website by using google login button but that google login button doesnt perform any event and I am not getting any error on browser console.
2. Currently I have used the attribute approval: force ,till this time on clicking the login button if multiple gmail ids are logged in it ask through which id I want to login.But here I get each time the approval popup which is irritating for the user if he/she is using same id for login. So, I want to remove the approval:force ,But if i do so then as soon as my application reloads the api gets automatically called,and start fetching information. 
   I need it should still ask me from which account I want to login